# Quitar un cheked oculto con cualquier click con JS o Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, css, checkbox

Hola que tal me gustaría saber si hay una forma de quitar el checked o que sea unchecked con cualquier click a cualquier parte de la pantalla, ya sea con JS o Jquery, estoy usando HTML y CSS para esta funcionalidad

Me explico, tengo un navbar que si le da el click al icono de buscar hace la función de un checkbox donde se activa y muestra el panel de búsqueda

```
<label for="show-search" class="search-icon"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></label>
       <form id="#" class="search-box">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Buscar" class="search_box">
            <button type="submit" class="go-icon"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
       </form>
```

Aqui el CSS que hace que se oculte

```
.wrapper input[type="checkbox"]{
  display: none;
}
.wrapper #show-search:checked ~ .search-box{
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

Prácticamente da un click y se muestra el search_box, pero mi intención es que no sea necesario dar click en la X que tiene, necesito que con cualquier click se quite el search_box es para comodidad de usuario.

Anexo un link donde encontré el código

https://www.codingnepalweb.com/2021/02/responsive-dropdown-menu-bar-with-search-bar.html

por si les llega a servir es un gran Navbar solo quiero modificar lo del checkbox oculto

Muchas gracias por su atención

Answer (score 0):

Podrias hacer eso con JS por medio de una referencia al input de la barra de búsqueda. Un detalle a tener en cuenta es que en el ejemplo que pasaste, el fondo blanco con el texto de ***Responsive Dropdown Menu Bar with Searchbox
using only HTML & CSS - Flexbox*** solo tiene como elemento el texto, es decir, no hay fondo. Esto te lo comento porque sino podrias obtener una referencia al fondo y usar el evento para *togglear* el checkbox, pero en este caso particular, a mi entendimiento, no es posible.

La solucion que planteo a continuación permite cerrar el checkbox clickeando en cualquier lado **siempre y cuando el usuario haya clickeado el cuadro de texto que aparece cuando el checkbox está activo**.

Primero le agregamos el atributo `id` al input de busqueda.

```
<form action="#" class="search-box">
    <!-- Le agregas un id al input con id="search-input" -->
    <input type="text" id="search-input" placeholder="Type Something to Search..." required>
    <button type="submit" class="go-icon"><i class="fas fa-long-arrow-alt-right"></i></button>
  </form>
```

En el JS, agregás lo siguiente

```
class App {
   constructor() {
       this.addInputListener();
   }

   addInputListener() {
       // Obteniendo una referencia al checkbox para desactivarlo.
       const checkbox = document.querySelector("#show-search");

       // Obteniendo una referencia al input donde escribis para buscar
       const searchInput = document.querySelector("#search-input");

       // Agregando el avento "focusout"
       searchInput.addEventListener("focusout", function() {
           checkbox.checked = false;
       })
    }
 }

 new App();
```